# If a thread locks a mutex and doesn't unlock it, shouldn't be the rest of threads blocked?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, mutex

The output of the code below is 4000;
 why it's 4000 if the thread which have the mutex doesn't release it. I though it will be a deadlock, in the main i wait for all the functions to finish.

```
int M = 1000;
HANDLE mutex;
DWORD WINAPI thread_function(LPVOID param) // The thread function
{
    long aux;
    WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        aux = count;         //count is global
        aux++;
        Sleep(0.5);
        count = aux;
    }
    /*ReleaseMutex(mutex);*/
    return (DWORD)0;
}
int main()
{
    int N = 4;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&gSection);
    HANDLE* iThread = (HANDLE*)malloc(N * sizeof(HANDLE));
    mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)    // N = 4, i create 4 threads
    {
        iThread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread_function, mutex, 0, NULL);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(4, iThread, TRUE, INFINITE); // I wait for all threads to finish.
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

expected result is deadlock, actual result is 4000(count = 4000).

Comment: No error checking. Look at return codes and GetLastError() as appropriate and you will probably figure out the answer on your own.

Comment: The mutex forces all 4 threads to execute in sequence. When the first thread that gets it is done and gone, it loses ownership. Meaning this code doesn't only wait for a thread to stop doing its work, it waits for the thread to get deleted too. So this code is far more inefficient than a single-thread program would be.

Comment: For future reference, please tag questions about Windows threads with [tag:winapi]. That draws attention to the question from right kind of people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other threads are blocked until the thread holding the mutex ends. With the (normal) end of the thread the mutex is released automatically since nobody is left holding it. But using that feature is bad coding practice. You should always release a mutex explicit.

Comment: "*the mutex is released automatically*" - not just **released** but **abandoned**. A subsequent wait operation on the mutex will report `WAIT_ABANDONED`: "*The specified object is a mutex object that **was not released** by the thread that owned the mutex object before the owning thread terminated. Ownership of the mutex object is granted to the calling thread and the **mutex state is set to nonsignaled***". A lot of programmers don't handle `WAIT_ABANDONED` correctly. See [Understanding the consequences of WAIT_ABANDONED](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050912-14/?p=34253).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau This case was not a shared memory example but a multi threading example with memory shared between threads. So in this case you usually don't have to handle it correctly since you need to do some interesting stuff like explicitly terminating a thread to get to a point where the WATI_ABANDONED state doesn't mean the thread exited normally and doesn't take program your whole program with it.